# How to combine similar methods into one

Tags: java, android, refactoring

I want to combine the methods `runSec` and `runMin` of moving the hands in one method. These methods move the minute and second hands on the clock face Help, thank you.

```
public void settTime(int seconds) {
  if(isTimer)
   return;
    tTime = seconds;
     int minutes = seconds / 60;
     int hours = minutes / 60;
     minutes = minutes % 60;
     seconds = seconds % 60;    
     tTimeLabel.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds));
      runSec(seconds);
      runMin(minutes);
}

public void runSec(int seconds) {
 RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(seconds * 6, seconds * 6,
 Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
 rotateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
 csecond.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
}

public void runMin(int minutes) {
 RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(minutes * 6, minutes * 6,
 Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
 rotateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
cminute.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't get the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void runMin(int minutes) {
   cminute.startAnimation(createAnimation(minutes*6));
}

public void runSec(int seconds) {
  csecond.startAnimation(createAnimation(seconds*6));
}

public RotateAnimation createAnimation(int time) {
   RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(time, time,
   Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
   rotateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
   return rotateAnimation;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your methods are nearly identical already. Just pass in another argument which will take the value `csecond` or `cminute` as appropriate.

```
public void runHand(int amount, Hand hand) {
  RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(amount * 6, amount * 6,
  Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
  rotateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
  hand.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you do same things in both method so you can replace with any one-

```
public void runMinorSec(int time) {
 RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(time * 6, minutes * 6,
 Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
 rotateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
 cminute.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
}
```

and you can call method like

```
  runMinorSec(seconds);
  runMinorSec(minutes);
```

But you can concat two method like this -

```
public void runSecOrMin(int time, boolean isSec) {
 if(isSec){
    RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(seconds * 6, seconds * 6,
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    rotateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
    csecond.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
 }else{
    RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(minutes * 6, minutes * 6,
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    rotateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
    cminute.startAnimation(rotateAnimation); 
 }
}
```

..

```
runSecOrMin(seconds,true);
runSecOrMin(minutes,false);
```

Answer (score 0):

The methods appear identical, and the reason seems easy to guess.  Both the second and minute hands on a clock have the same animation per unit (1/60th of a rotation).  So, it just comes down to syntax in the end.  If you'd like, substitute, the variable name `minutesOrSeconds` with something else.

```
public enum TimeType {SECOND, MINUTE}

public void runMin(int time, TimeType timeType) {
    RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(time* 6, time* 6,
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    rotateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
    if (TimeType == SECOND) {
        csecond.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
    } else if (TimeType == MINUTE) {
        cminute.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually the last line is different

Answer (score 0):

Try this, just pass the view as parameter, csecond and cminute.

```
public void runMin(int time, View target) {
    RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(time * 6, time * 6,
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    rotateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
    target.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I examined your 2 methods and have not found any difference except name of the argument. If I am right, just call this method `run(int time)` and replace all places where you use `minutes` and `seconds` by time. Mention in javadoc that time may be either in minutes or in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void runTime(int seconds, int minutes) 
{
 RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(seconds * 6, seconds * 6,
 Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
 RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(minutes * 6, minutes * 6,
 Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
 rotateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
 csecond.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
 cminute.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
}
```